# How to insert one node into an abstract syntax tree by javascript (esprima)

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, esprima

there is a question about esprima and inserting an ast node.

I try to generate one ast node to replace other node with new node , (node = newNode) , but It does't work.

```
    estraverse.traverse(tree, {
enter(node, parent) {
try {
    if (node.type === "ExpressionStatement") {
        if(node.expression.right.type == "FunctionExpression"){
            // the id attribution can be replaced
            node.expression.right.id = node.expression.left;
            // but node can not be replaced
            node = node.expression.right;
            node.type = "FunctionDeclaration";
        }
    }
} catch (error) {

}
},});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code snippet you shared, you are using estraverse to parse through the AST. For replacing a node, you need to use the estraverse.replace API. You can check the details in the documentation for estraverse.replace, but in general when you find the node to replace (Ex. if(node=='Expression Statement'){ .... }) you need to return the new node to this function which will replace the current node.

//node is replaced by Newnode

```
result = estraverse.replace(AST, {
    leave: function (node) {
        if (node.type == 'Expression Statement')
            return Newnode;
    }
});
```

One point you need to take care is to make sure the Newnode does not break the AST syntax in anyway. Best way I found was to get the Newnode by converting a code snippet into AST and then grabbing the respective node out of it. This makes sure the structure remains ecmascript compliant.